# C# object with nested properties

Tags: c#, rest, model

When I post the 'content' to the API, it fails. I checked the actual JSON and this is what is outputted. I believe the AttachmentList array has a [0] index in it which is why it failed. How can I go about fixing the model to match what the API is requiring?

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON, more like a watch on the list. what's the value of `requestData`?

Comment: Oh, that screenshot is a snippet of the entire JSON.

Comment: Okay, but that screenshot is not showing a JSON string, but some kind of object graph. What does the string representation look like?

Comment: I believe `0` is an index, which means `AttachmentList` contains 1 item, which is correct.

Comment: @JonathonChase, this is entire value of requestData

{"CustomerFirstName":"Test","CustomerLastName":"Test","AttachmentList":[{"Name":"1be90abf-0ba2-4fcd-968c-7aef59ead16d.jpg","FileName":"1be90abf-0ba2-4fcd-968c-7aef59ead16d.jpg","Description":"upload","Data":"9j4AAQSkZ"}]}

Comment: It looks like the API wants the values of each Attachment in camelCase instead of PascalCase.

Comment: D'oh! That was it.. thanks!